# Shopify storefront api create cart mutation returns HTML response

Tags: javascript, next.js, shopify, shopify-api

I am building an e-commerce with Next.js and Shopify storefront API.
So far I am listing all the products meaning that the connection with the API works fine.

The moment I call the following function to add a product for the first time (meaning that a new cart has to be created) I get an error:

```
export async function addToCart(itemId: string, quantity: string) {
  const createCartMutation = gql`
    mutation createCart($cartInput: CartInput) {
      cartCreate(input: $cartInput) {
        cart {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  const variables = {
    cartInput: {
      lines: [
        {
          quantity: parseInt(quantity),
          merchandiseId: itemId,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  try {
    const d = await graphQLClient.request(createCartMutation, variables);
    return d;
  } catch (error: any) {
    debugger;
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

ERROR:

[image]

the only 2 products have no variants therefore the `itemId` is the actual product id rather than the variant id.

I can'r figure out what is needed to make this work. Any help would much appreciated. Thank you

UPDATE
If I try the same mutation in the GRaphQl explorer provided by shopify it works correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next config didn't have the variables configured, it worked when pulling products from Shopify even without environment variables configured, I guess it's different when you do mutations. I am not sure, I will find out.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    NEXT_SHOPIFY_STORE_DOMAIN: process.env.NEXT_SHOPIFY_STORE_DOMAIN,
    NEXT_SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESSTOKEN:
      process.env.NEXT_SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_ACCESSTOKEN,
  },
};
```